# Parent Class has "text-align:center" but child stays left-aligned

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment, display

Here I have the snippet of HTML

```
   <header id="showcase">
        <div class="showcase-content">
            <h1>The Sky Is The Limit</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore facere adipisci corporis molestiae voluptatum natus.</p>
            <a class = " readmore"href="#what">Read more</a>
        </div>

    </header>
```

Below is the CSS for it

```
#showcase .showcase-content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 4rem;
    /* Overlay */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.readmore{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 7rem;
    color:white;
    background: #93cb52;
    left: 50%; 
}
```

The issue is that the *readmore* class has an overridden display:inline-block; and *.showcase-content* class has **text-align:center**; but *readmore* still stays left-aligned.

Comment: inline-block isn't your issue. Remove the left property and add margin: auto. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/75j02hd6/1/

Answer (score 0):

just make a little changes to your code:

change the code "dislay:flex" to "display:block".

[Refer Here](https://codepen.io/asad7880/pen/abzWEOV) Thanks

```
#showcase .showcase-content{
display: block;
flex-direction: column;
text-align: center;
justify-content: center;
height: 100%;
padding: 4rem;
/* Overlay */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.readmore{
display:inline-block;
width: 7rem;
color:white;
background: #93cb52;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

left doesn't work  until you set it position: absolute; property. but, better way is remove left property and give margin: auto; see here,

```css
#showcase .showcase-content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 4rem;
    /* Overlay */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.readmore{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 7rem;
    color:white;
    background: #93cb52;
   margin: auto;
}
```

```html
 <header id="showcase">
        <div class="showcase-content">
            <h1>The Sky Is The Limit</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore facere adipisci corporis molestiae voluptatum natus.</p>
            <a class = " readmore"href="#what">Read more</a>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<header id="showcase">
        <div class="showcase-content">
            <h1>The Sky Is The Limit</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore facere adipisci corporis molestiae voluptatum natus.</p>
          <p>  <a class = " readmore"href="#what">Read more</a></p>
        </div>
    </header>
```

just add one paragraph tag thats it

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin: auto` to the button. You gave a particular width to the button which does not contain the full width of the row. And you gave the left not apply because you can give the left, right, top, bottom property with the position. So, left does not work.

```css
#showcase .showcase-content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 4rem;
    /* Overlay */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.readmore{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 7rem;
    color:white;
    background: #93cb52;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
 <header id="showcase">
        <div class="showcase-content">
            <h1>The Sky Is The Limit</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore facere adipisci corporis molestiae voluptatum natus.</p>
            <a class = " readmore"href="#what">Read more</a>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be various solutions as provided by all others for this problem. But I will let you know that you have to understand the **CSS Flexbox Layout Module** like `display:flex` property uses & features of CSS from here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Solutions:

**1-** Just remove `display:flex;` line form the css class. (without display: flex;)

**2-** Just add `align-items: center;` into class `.showcase-content` which will align all the child content toward center.

For your scenario, Solution:2 will definitely help you. **Good Luck :)**

Comment: Number 2 did that job. Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

Either wrap your button in html `center` tag:

```html
<center><a class=" readmore" href="#what">Read more button</a></center>
```

or use this style:

```css
margin: 0 auto;
width: 7rem;
```

Comment: While this could answer the question, a sample of the code after being fixed is more useful.